# HM-10 Bluetooth Module - BLE 4.0 Keep Losing Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, hm-10

has anyone tried using HM-10 Bluetooth module?

I'm able to pair with it using an Android device and passing the pre-defined PIN. Based on the UART return, the pairing is successful (module returns OK+CONN - means a connection was established)

However, after a few seconds (2-3), the UART receives OK+LOST; means the connection was lost. Also, the LED starts blinking (normally, when a connection is active, it stays lit)

Is this normal behaviour for bluetooth in general or the HM-10 module.

This is the product's website: http://www.jnhuamao.cn/bluetooth.asp?ID=1

Comment: I'm also having problems with the BLE module. I try to pair it. Put in the pincode.. Terminal give back +CONNECTED (its another firmware I think). Than its not in the list connected devices. But in android it said pairing... (not in bounded devices :()

Comment: What is your android version??

Comment: Hi Johan, im using android 4.0.4

Comment: Hmm. Ok, maybe try it with some phone with 4.4. It has some bug fixes (Google said). I think i'm gonna order a HM-10 also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but HM -10 don't support rfcom. It's mean that you must use GATT functionality for communication. Entity of BLE is usage of minimum data package as it possible, so BLE don't hold the connection all times and use something like statuses [attributes].
So, few code lines for example, how work with BLE:
1.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(DEVICE_ADDR);
```

That's device initiation, the same like with simple bluetooth, where DEVICE_ADDR is the MAC of your BLE(how to find this address you can find in google or stack overflow, its trivial)

```
2. 

   BluetoothGattService mBluetoothGattService; 
   BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
   BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = mBluetoothGatt.getServices();

                    for(BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
                        if("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb".equals(gattService.getUuid().toString()))
                        {
                            mBluetoothGattService = gattService;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                }
            }
        };
```

So, what this code mean: if u can see from this part of code, i describe how GATT service find. This service needed for "attribute" communication. gattService.getUuid() has few uuids for communication(4 in my module), some of them used for RX, some for TX etc. "0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" that is one of uuid that use for communication thats why i check it.
The final part of code is message sending:

```
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic =         mBluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
String msg = "HELLO BLE =)";
        byte b = 0x00;
        byte[] temp = msg.getBytes();
        byte[] tx = new byte[temp.length + 1];
        tx[0] = b;
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            tx[i+1] = temp[i];

        gattCharacteristic.setValue(tx);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
```

After sending message contain hold on and you can send another message or can close connection.
More info, you can find on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html.
PS: MAC address of your module can find with ble scanner code or with AT cmd:
on my firmware AT+ADDR or AT+LADDR
About UUIDs usage: not sure, but in my case, i find it with next AT+UUID [Get/Set system SERVER_UUID] -> Response +UUID=0xFFE0, AT+CHAR [Get/Set system CHAR_UUID] - Response +CHAR=0xFFE1. Thats why i make conclusion that UUID which i must use fe "0000[ffe0/is 0xFFE0 from AT response]-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"